# how to fetch a nested resource for every component in React router dom route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I have some nested routes that look like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={"/"}>
    <HomepageContainer />
  </Route>
  <Route path={"/users"}>
    <UsersContainer />
  </Route>
  <Route path={"/users/new"}>
    <NewUserContainer />
  </Route>
  <Route path={"/users/:userId/edit"}>
    <EditUserContainer />
  </Route>
  <Route path={"/users/:userId/comments"}>
    <UserCommentsContainer />
  </Route>
  <Route path={"/users/:userId/comments/:commentId"}>
    <UserCommentContainer />
  </Route>
  <Route render={() => <Redirect to={"/"} />} />
</Switch>
```

Three of which have a userId in the URL params and inside those components I fetch a user inside of a `useEffect` hook.

Is there a way for react-router-dom to allow me to do this fetch in a single place and make the result available to EditUserContainer, UserCommentsContainer and UserCommentContainer?

Comment: you can create an object that houses custom hooks and all data you need for/from those elements that you export/import in said components.

Comment: an example for a shared hook ( named 'routerHook' ) : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-demo-hook-routing-forked-jjz7n?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution I'm happy with and not sure why I didn't think of it initially (still learning React!)

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={"/"}>
    <HomepageContainer />
  </Route>
  <Route path={"/users"}>
    <UsersContainer />
  </Route>
  <Route path={"/users/new"}>
    <NewUserContainer />
  </Route>
  <Route path={"/users/:userId/edit"} render={() => {
    <CurrentUserContainer>
      <EditUserContainer />
    </CurrentUserContainer>
  }} />
  <Route path={"/users/:userId/comments"} render={() => {
    <CurrentUserContainer>
      <UserCommentsContainer />
    </CurrentUserContainer>
  }} />
  <Route path={"/users/:userId/comments/:commentId"} render={() => {
    <CurrentUserContainer>
      <UserCommentContainer />
    </CurrentUserContainer>
  }} />
  <Route render={() => <Redirect to={"/"} />} />
</Switch>
```

Wrapping each of the nested user components in a parent CurrentUserContainer that will be responsible for doing the fetch and setting the state, making it available where needed.